# To the point: in search of an iPhone independent way of drawing?

Tags: ios, swift, drawrect, points

The iPhone 5 has a size of 320x568 points, whereas the iPhone 7 has a screen size of 375x667 points.

Say I have a ViewController subclass in which I create a view (`someView`), whose frame is meant to fill the iPhone 7 screen. I hardcode this as follows:

```
let origin = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
let size = CGSize(width: 375.0, height: 667.0)
let frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)
let someView = SomeView(frame: frame)
```

In `someView`'s `override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)` method I draw an oval:

```
let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)
UIColor.green.setFill()
path.fill()
```

If I run this in the iPhone 7 simulator I generate a green oval that fills the screen. If, however, I run this in the iPhone 5 simulator part of the oval is off the screen.

My question is, when working in points do you have to choose sizes that are dependent on the iPhone device? i.e. have loads of `if` statements where the size of what you draw depends on the device? Or is there something that you can do, which will automatically shrink your sizes if they're too big for the screen? i.e. akin to drawing in an `auto layout` fashion?

Thanks.

Comment: By far, you are giving an exceptional example of why to use auto layout instead of frames. But assuming you *must* use frames for some reason the only thing you can do is set up application wide variables with the screen size and in each and every frame that matters, use computed values (probably a percentage) for X/Y and height/width. (Yep, ugly. Which is why I'd bite the bullet and refactor to use auto layout.)

Comment: @dfd Thanks for your comment. I had a feeling that was so. Does this then make drawing applications, like PaintCode, trickier to use? I was hoping of including a long bezier code made using PaintCode, but it moves to points outside of the frame...

Comment: I haven't used PaintCode so I can't comment. But if you have a closed bezier path you should be able to turn it into a CAShapeLayer and use that in a scalable view.

Comment: @dfd Why would you set up an application wide variable with the screen size? 1. Just base things on the parent view size. 2. Even if you mistakenly based things on the screen size, you can access that without the need to setup extra globals. Just use `UIScreen`.

Comment: If you paint something that is bigger than the physical resolution, you should use scrollView and put your view inside it.

Comment: @rmaddy, you're correct. I wasn't thinking in any other terms than what's easiest in most cases. I've been programming since 1984 and it *felt* best as an application-wide variable for (I guess) performance reasons. As for UIScreen? I was close. :-) That is application-wide. LOL. As for parent view size? I didn't glean from the OP that the parent would *always* be full screen. (I see where it's implied, but wanted something a bit more flexible.) Good points.